# Start and stop local mysql instance from within application

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have been tasked with writing some in-house management software. This software talks to an online MySQL database. However, if there is no internet connection then the system should use a local "offline" MySQL database instead.

At first, I attempted to do this with remote MySQL and local SQLCE. Sadly, the query strings are so different that it is not feasible.

My question then is; how can I start an instance of MySQL on a specific port when loading the application, then shut down the instance when the software is closed?

I have bundled XAMPP with a piece of software before, but am unsure if that is the correct approach in this case?

```
ProcessStartInfo test = new ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"mysqldb\bin");
        test.FileName = @"mysqld.exe";
        test.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps install MySQL database localy and externaly. When the software is loading, just use the local database. When everything is okay, sync the local with the live database and switch the database link from the local to the live. Do not stop the local database because if internet is going down, you need to be able to save data using the local database.

Always sync live with local, so if Internet is up, use the live database but also the local. Everything need to be sync. Data will be then always on the computer as "backup" or offline database and your live database wlll have everything from everywhere.

Use a buffer, so you'll need loose your query in the void. Also, under Windows, you can use service to start and stop MySQL.

I hope I answered a fews of yours questions.

Comment: Good answer, sadly multiple people will be working from the same source, the issue is when they go out on site and have no internet access (because they are 10m up some scaffolding for instance)

Comment: What type of query you run when they have no Internet Access ? Only UPDATE and INSERT ? Or you doing SELECT also ? Because you could just store the query until Internet is okay and do a batch update. This is how we work here with our RFID.

Comment: In short everything, if the remote connection is available then it will run the query on that DB, if not it will run it on local DB

Answer (score 0):

e.g. PathtoMysql would be like C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin

Start the server by running mysqld.exe in the install path.

Stop it with MySqlAdmin -u root -p rootpassword Shutdown

Port number is going to be on, will be in my.ini

Comment: So you are saying to create the my.ini file on startup and call the mysql instance from the software path with mysqld?

Comment: On startup. Ony if you are going to keep changing it. On install would be more logical but yes mysqld starts the server up

Answer (score 0):

*Even the question is old now, hopefully this will help any one in the future. Please note that this for WPF application, a little edit needed*

Add this namespace to your project:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Embed the MySQL server withing your application directory:

```
YOUR APP DIR
..mysql-server   <=== This is the mysql server directory under your App dir.
```

Now in the `load` event start the mysql server:

```
  Process mysqlCMD = new Process();
  mysqlCMD.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\mysql-server\\bin\\mysqld.exe";
  mysqlCMD.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // This is to hide the black CMD window
  mysqlCMD.Start();
```

In the `closing` event you must stop mysql server, otherwise you will have problems when you start it next time:

```
  Process mysqlCloseCMD = new Process();
  mysqlCloseCMD.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\mysql-server\\bin\\mysqladmin.exe";
  mysqlCloseCMD.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  mysqlCloseCMD.StartInfo.Arguments = "--user=root shutdown";
  mysqlCloseCMD.Start();
```